# MySQL server configuration cloud

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wonder how my optimal MySQL server configuration would look like when I am using an Amazon Cloud Server which is being adapted from 8GB RAM to 144GB Ram according to the traffic peaks. I don't want to change the MySQL configuration every time I change the hardware resources of my server. Is there a suitable configuration for things like this?

Further I wonder which configurations are especially important for my case:

- It is a Forum with 400-2500 live users online (Analytics real time analysis)
- We got an authentication and session-check (two php files, which do 1-2 small SQL queries) which is being called 40,000 user x 4times per hour (I mentioned this because I worry about cached results = session check for this user may fail?)

In the past our database server went offline at peak times before all resources (CPU/RAM/Disk I/O, Bandwidth) has been used completely. Thus I think that we use a bad configuration currently. What is about the property `max_connections` , this is currently 500. Would it help to set it up to something like 2000 for servers of my size?

Should I use a perssistant PDO connection for the session-check / authentication?

Comment: As far as I know, changing RAM available to MySQL requires MySQL to be restarted.  Doing that will flush everything that has been cached and cause a performance hit for a time, until the cache refills.  Benchmark where your performance issues are. Just adding RAM may not be the solution, or at least not the best one.  If max_connections is 500, and you have 2500 users online at peak times, some of them may not get a connection some of the time.  You can measure that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2453308/141172

Comment: Allow me also to recommend [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.com/) in case you don't know it. It will help you understand some things about the server (it has helped me at least) :)

Comment: kentor, you are talking EC2, right ? What is the actual problem you have faced?

Comment: Yes I am Drew. We got a peak of 2,5k live users and the mysql server wasn't answering anymore, but SSH access was possible.